# Replace values in factor based on frequency of levels

Tags: r

Here is a data frame:

```
vegetables <- c("carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots")
animals <- c("cats", "dogs", "dogs", "fish", "cats")
df <- data.frame(vegetables, animals)
```

Looks like:

```
> df
  vegetables animals
1    carrots    cats
2    carrots    dogs
3    carrots    dogs
4    carrots    fish
5    carrots    cats
```

If I wanted to remove rows where the levels frequency was below e.g. 2 (so fish in the example df) then remove that row:

```
for ( i in names(df) ) {
  df <- subset(df, with(df, df[,i] %in% names(which(table(df[,i]) >= 2))))
}

> df
  vegetables animals
1    carrots    cats
2    carrots    dogs
3    carrots    dogs
5    carrots    cats
```

But what if I don't want to remove the observation but instead replace fish with "bla".

How would I do that?

Desired output:

```
> df
  vegetables animals
1    carrots    cats
2    carrots    dogs
3    carrots    dogs
4    carrots    bla
5    carrots    cats
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[,  .I[.N > 1], by = .(vegetables, animals)]$V1]
```

If we want to replace the low frequency item in each column with 'bla'

```
threshold <- 1
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
setDT(df)
for(j in seq_along(df)){
  df[, N := .N, c(names(df)[j])][N == threshold, names(df)[j] := "bla"][, N := NULL][]
  }
```

Comment: @DougFir Are you saying that you want to have 'bla' in all the columns that have less number of elements?  IN that case, the 'vegetables' have only a single element.  So, you may need a threshold

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if the levels of variable are important, if not, you could do the following with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` 
    as option in `data.frame`

```
vegetables <- c("carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots")
animals <- c("cats", "dogs", "dogs", "fish", "cats")
DF <- data.frame(vegetables, animals,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

threshold = 2
DF$animals[ DF$animals == names(which(table(DF$animals) < threshold)) ] = "foo"

DF
#  vegetables animals
#1    carrots    cats
#2    carrots    dogs
#3    carrots    dogs
#4    carrots     foo
#5    carrots    cats
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try to use it in my real world data frame but the stringsAsFactors=FALSE was causing me issues

Answer (score 4):

You can just update the levels, using a table to index which ones to change:

```
levels(df$animals)[table(df$animals) < 2] <- 'bla'

df
##   vegetables animals
## 1    carrots    cats
## 2    carrots    dogs
## 3    carrots    dogs
## 4    carrots     bla
## 5    carrots    cats
```

Comment: wow! This works too and is simplest. On the one hand I want to be loyal to @akrun and maintain his answer since he was really patient and helped me a lot in the comments (now deleted). On the other hand this is the simplest and appears best option

Comment: This is so great! So elegant!